# Unknown typename "vector" and "std" when forming an algorithm

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++, in this assignment, I've made a program that sorts the given array in ascending order using the bucket sort algorithm. I have encountered numerous errors regarding the use of the vector library and when expressing the variables used to contain the array.

Is there a simpler implementation of the bucket sort of natural numbers? The examples I found were using bucket sort to sort alphabets decimals...etc which made it confusing for me to understand the basics when applied to positive whole numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

//function declaration
void display(int arr[], int size);
int getMax(int arr[], int size);
void bucketSort(int arr[], int size);

using namespace std;

void display(int arr[], int size) {
    int i, m;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << m; {
            m = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return m;
}

void bucketSort(int arr[], int size) {
    //variables
    int max, bucket = 10, divider, i, j, k;

    //10 buckets
    vector B[bucket];

    //find max and min
    max = getMax(arr, size);

    divider = ceil(float(max + 1) / bucket);

    //insert element into bucket
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        j = floor( arr[i] / divider );
        B[j].push_back(arr[i]);
    }

    //sort elements in the buckets
    for(i = 0; i < bucket; i++) {
        sort(B[i].begin(), B[i].end());
    }

    //append back the elements from the buckets
    k = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < bucket; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < B[i].size(); j++) {
            arr[k++] = B[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    //unsorted elements
    int arr[] = {22,45,12,8,10,6,72,81,33,18,50,14};

    //size of the array
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    //output unsorted elements
    display(arr, n);

    //sort the elements
    bucketSort(arr, n);

    //display sorted elements
    display(arr, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, this has nothing to do with C so please do not tag it as such.

Comment: `return m;` You cannot return values from a `void` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just ask for a vector... you have to tell it, a vector of *what*?

In your case it looks like you want an array of vectors of `int`s, so:

```
vector<int> B[bucket];
```

Your next problem is that you can't have an array of variable size.

Please refer to your C++ book for more information on all of this stuff.

Comment: @RSahu Oh yeah that seems right, thanks

Comment: Note that this (as it is in OP) is ill-formed unless `bucket` is changed to be a compile time constant.

Comment: Yeah it's all a big mess